# OpenTelemetry with TimerTrigger Azure Functions

Tags: c#, .net, azure-functions, open-telemetry

I instrumented opentelemetry for two types of Azure Functions: **HttpTrigger** and **TimerTrigger**.
The former works fine thanks to `.AddAspNetCoreInstrumentation()` middleware. During its call over HTTP it creates a parent trace which is later shared with other HTTP calls within the function's code and I have a nice nested trace where all function's activities are under their parent.
However with the **TimeTrigger** Azure Function I cannot achieve that probably because `.AddAspNetCoreInstrumentation()` middleware doesn't kick in when TimeTrigger function is executed thus no parent trace is created and all HTTP calls within the function's code behave independently and cannot be grouped under one trace creating a mess.

Here are Grafana screenshots to visualize the problem.

Expected correct result of **HttpTrigger** function:

[image: HttpTrigger]

Individual non-grouped traces of **TimeTrigger** function:

[image: TimeTrigger]

Here is the code I have.

**Startup:**

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using OpenTelemetry;
using OpenTelemetry.Logs;
using OpenTelemetry.Metrics;
using OpenTelemetry.Resources;
using OpenTelemetry.Trace;

[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(FunctionsOpenTelemetry.Startup))]
namespace FunctionsOpenTelemetry
{
    public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
    {
        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            // OpenTelemetry Resource to be associated with traces
            var openTelemetryResourceBuilder = ResourceBuilder.CreateDefault().AddService("Reporting-Serivce");

            // Enable Tracing with OpenTelemetry
            var openTelemetryTracerProvider = Sdk.CreateTracerProviderBuilder()
                .SetResourceBuilder(openTelemetryResourceBuilder)
                .SetSampler(new AlwaysOnSampler())
                .AddHttpClientInstrumentation(g => g.Filter = context => !context.RequestUri.ToString().Contains("127.0.0.1"))
                .AddAspNetCoreInstrumentation()
                .AddConsoleExporter()
                .AddJaegerExporter()
                .Build();
            builder.Services.AddSingleton(openTelemetryTracerProvider);
        }
    }
}
```

**Functions code:**

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System.Net.Http;

namespace FunctionsOpenTelemetry
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task Run1([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
        {
            DoTenHttpRequests();
        }

        [FunctionName("Function2")]
        public static async Task Run2([TimerTrigger("0 */5 * * * *")] TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
        {
            DoTenHttpRequests();
        }

        private static void DoTenHttpRequests()
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                var client = new HttpClient();
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://www.google.com");
                client.GetAsync("/").GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**.csproj:**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="4.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="OpenTelemetry.Exporter.Console" Version="1.2.0-rc2" />
    <PackageReference Include="OpenTelemetry.Instrumentation.AspNetCore" Version="1.0.0-rc9" />
    <PackageReference Include="OpenTelemetry.Instrumentation.Http" Version="1.0.0-rc9" />
    <PackageReference Include="OpenTelemetry.Exporter.Jaeger" Version="1.2.0-rc2" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Summarizing my question: how can I instrument **TimeTrigger** Azure Functions so they create an initial parent trace and share it within their code like **HttpTrigger** function does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my own answer after a couple of days of investigation and conversations on GitHub.

As of **Jan 2023** there is no built in .NET middleware to support automatic instrumentation of **TimerTrigger** Azure Functions which was confirmed at [project's GitHub page](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-dotnet/issues/4042). The workaround will be a manual instrumentation which requires adding code in each function creating a parent span.

Below is a working example I ended up with.

**Startup.cs:**

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using OpenTelemetry;
using OpenTelemetry.Logs;
using OpenTelemetry.Metrics;
using OpenTelemetry.Resources;
using OpenTelemetry.Trace;

[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(FunctionsOpenTelemetry.Startup))]
namespace FunctionsOpenTelemetry
{
    public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
    {
        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            // OpenTelemetry Resource to be associated with traces
            var openTelemetryResourceBuilder = ResourceBuilder.CreateDefault().AddService("POC-DotNet-Instrumentation");

            // Enable Tracing with OpenTelemetry
            var openTelemetryTracerProvider = Sdk.CreateTracerProviderBuilder()
                .SetResourceBuilder(openTelemetryResourceBuilder)
                .SetSampler(new AlwaysOnSampler())
                .AddSource("TimerTriggerSource")
                .AddHttpClientInstrumentation(g => g.Filter = context => !context.RequestUri.ToString().Contains("127.0.0.1"))
                .AddAspNetCoreInstrumentation()
                .AddConsoleExporter()
                .AddJaegerExporter()
                .Build();
            builder.Services.AddSingleton(openTelemetryTracerProvider);
        }
    }
}
```

**Functions code:**

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System.Net.Http;
using OpenTelemetry.Trace;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace FunctionsOpenTelemetry
{
    public class Function1
    {
        private static readonly ActivitySource activitySource = new("TimerTriggerSource");

        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public async Task Run1([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
        {
            DoTenHttpRequests();
        }

        [FunctionName("Function2")]
        public async Task Run2([TimerTrigger("0 */1 * * * *")] TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
        {
            using var activity = activitySource.StartActivity("/timertrigger/Function2");

            try
            {
                DoTenHttpRequests();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                activity.SetStatus(Status.Error.WithDescription(ex.Message));
                throw;
            }
        }

        private static void DoTenHttpRequests()
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                var client = new HttpClient();
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://www.google.com");
                client.GetAsync("/").GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: any ideas if my issue is similar? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75817875/azure-open-telemetry-activity-is-null-few-min-after-app-start